# Inner shadow Jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

[image]

I have a figma design the same as image. I want to create a component with jetpack compose koltin.

Because I just learned about jetpack compose, I haven't figured out what I need to do yet.

Please help me, thank you for your help!

Comment: Would be great to see what you’ve tried so far and where you are stuck